# Make JSHint to show error in function's name

Tags: javascript, jshint

I read a lot about JSHint configurator but missed one moment that would be helpful for me. For example when i write `document.geetElementById` (there is an extra e) it says nothing. Is there any way to make JSHint to show errors like this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot configure it like that, because it can't determine whether document has a `geetElementById` method or not. (What if you tried adding one, that has almost the same name as a built-in function it *should* know about?)

On the other hand, if you mistyped `document` (depending on your settings) you would get a warning, because jshint looks for a variable declaration by that name. `document`, of course, is an exception, because you don't define it in your code, but it's globally available - jshint knows about this either because you set it using the `globals` option, or you've specified a `browser` environment.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. So, i should be more careful to avoid mistakes like this and there is no another way, right?

Comment: @IvanovIvan your IDE should possibly detect such mistakes, but sometimes it's very non-trivial to tell what attributes are present on an object without actually running the JS code.

Comment: i use Brackets and i can't find any plugins that provide ability to detect these mistakes.